# how to make 301 redirect by using PHP code, when the public_html and www are same

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel, http-status-code-301

I actually have PHP code for making 301 redirect on my site.Previously i done this by putting that PHP code on **\public_html\site_name\index.php** and that is not the same in **www\site_name\index**

(**\public_html and \www** are **not same** at that time).

But now these two folders(public_html and www) are showing the same content.Then now where i need to put the code?how **to achieve 301 redirect** using PHP **when the *\public_html* and *\www* folders are in same.**

Comment: So you want to redirect from your one site to your other site? But if they are now the same you don't have to redirect.

Comment: sorry manu i have to redirect to my own site like, http:\\my_site.com to http:\\www.my_site.com

Comment: ah okay. But when both folders showing the same content you should have your content only in one folder. And here you can place your redirect script.

Comment: Do you just want to add the www in front of the domain? you want to redirect `my_site.com` to `www.my_site.com`?

Comment: yes you are correct panama jack.

Comment: @manu but you see those folders are pointing same content.that means if i delete a file in www or public_html folder it reflects on other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, put this in your htaccess in the root of your site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

replace example.com with your domain.

Comment: `RewriteEngine OnRewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]` this was works fine.

Comment: Are you asking a question or something?

Comment: It is possible but it's not as efficient and as fast as letting the web server handle the redirect. The webserver(apache) will get the request first. Then execute the PHP code. It's best to stay with rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in each of the directories with the folowing statement

```
Redirect 301 / http://anyothersite.com/
```

Comment: but you see those folders are pointing same content.that means if i delete a file in www or public_html folder it reflects on other one.